# How would I use Beautiful Soup to scrape all paragraphs within one division?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some text from a site with Python and I'm new to this. The text is found in several paragraphs (individual `<p>` for each) but all of the text I want is in a single division with clearly defined attributes for `soup.find()`. Is there anything I can to do to pull the text? None of the paragraph tags are consistent. It looks something like this:

```
<div class="unique-phrase">

<p att1="00055" att2="A"> Text I want... </p>
<p att1="00056" att2="B"> Text I want... </p>
<p att1="00057" att2="C"> Text I want... </p>

</div>
```

I know I could probably cycle through the sequential "att1" (right? I'm new...) but I am hoping there will be a simpler way to accomplish this. The ideal result would be to store each paragraph individually in a list as a string. I've got it set up basically like this at the moment (but I've tried other things for `soup.findAll()`):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup

url = "http://www.url.com/url.html"
request = requests.get(url)
content = request.content
soup = bsoup(content, "lxml")

soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "unique-phrase"} )
```

but that's finding "NONE". Any help at all would be appreciated!

Comment: *Always and first of all, take a look at your `soup` to see if all the expected ingredients are in place.* What do you find in `soup`?  *Note:* It do not cause the issue but in newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)

Answer (score 1):

As you suggested, you need to find the `div` tag first, then find all `p` tags in the `div` tag and extract the texts into a list.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup

html = """
<div class="unique-phrase">

<p att1="00055" att2="A"> Text I want... </p>
<p att1="00056" att2="B"> Text I want... </p>
<p att1="00057" att2="C"> Text I want... </p>

</div>
"""
soup = bsoup(html, "lxml")

div_tag = soup.find("div", class_="unique-phrase")
paragraphs = [p_tag.get_text() for p_tag in div_tag.find_all("p")]
print(paragraphs)
```

Using the [`find_all()`](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#find-all) method, you don't need to rely on the `att1` attribute. The [`get_text()`](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#get-text) method also has some optional parameters such as `separator` and `strip`.

There is also a shorter way to accomplish this, that is to use [`soup.select()`](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#css-selectors) method with a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors):

```
paragraphs = [p_tag.get_text() for p_tag in soup.select(".unique-phrase p")]
print(paragraphs)
```

Answer (score 0):

To scrape all paragraphs within a specific division using Beautiful Soup, you can use the find or find_all method with the appropriate parameters.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Get the HTML source code of the web page
url = "http://www.url.com/url.html"
response = requests.get(url)
html_content = response.content

# Parse the HTML using BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")

# Find the specific division containing the paragraphs
division = soup.find("div", {"class": "unique-phrase"})

# Find all paragraphs within the division
paragraphs = division.find_all("p")

# Print the text content of each paragraph
paragraph_list =[]
for paragraph in paragraphs:
    print(paragraph.text)
    paragraph_list.append(paragraph.text)
```

Comment: what if you do not know the class name?